# get largest node value from firebase realtime database

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I have following structure of firebase data

```
booksDataList
   11 (Unique Book id )
        name   : abc
        author : auth1
        price  : 120
   12
        name   : lmn
        author : auth2
        price  : 100
   15
        name   : pqr
        author : auth1
        price  : 500
```

I want the price value which is greatest among all books. Please give any hint to get such value with respect to "booksDataList".

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in metadata for the size of a node in the Firebase Realtime Database. If you want to retrieve nodes based on their size, you will have to store that node size into the node yourself.

For example if you'd use `JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()).length` as the size, you'd get:

```
booksDataList
   11 (Unique Book id )
        data
            name   : abc
            author : auth1
            price  : 120
            size   : 52
   12
       data
           name   : lmnop
           author : auth2
           price  : 100
           size   : 54
   15
       data
           name   : pqrs
           author : auth1
           price  : 500
           size   : 53
```

And you can then get the largest node with:

```
ref.orderByChild("size").limitToLast(1)
```